# Convert 1d array into array of vectors

Tags: c#, arrays, vector, coordinates, points

i have a 48 element in a double array that contains XYZ coordinates of 16 points, i need to extract every single point from this array into Vector3 (x,y,z)
tried to loop over the array but somehow my loop is getting to the bounds of the array index like below

```
     {
        myVector = new Vector(myArray[i], myArray[i++], myArray[i+2]);
        Console.WriteLine(myVector);
     }
```

any ideas ?

Comment: You want `i+1` instead of `i++`. The latter changes the value of `i` so `i+2` really ends up being `<the original i> + 3`. Also, `i++` is post-increment so you're really getting `i` as the index instead of `i+1` like you're expecting.

Comment: Do you think you need to use `i++` here?  You likely intended to write `i + 1`.   If it wasn't a typo then you might want to brush up on the meanings of `++i` vs `i++` vs `i + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple:

```
 {
    myVector = new Vector(myArray[i], myArray[i+1], myArray[i+2]);
    Console.WriteLine(myVector);
 }
```

Explanation:

`i++` changes `i` value by adding `1` to it, `i+1` doesn't.

Comment: already did that but still getting System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' @marco salemo

Comment: Considering your code, if you are looping through a for statement, your maxvalue should be length - 3